# How to Install XAMPP on my ubuntu 16.04 32bit

Tags: server, software-installation, php, xampp

I'm trying to install Xampp Latest Version in my Ubuntu 16.10 32bit. In Xampp website I can't find a a 32 installer, all that they offer is 64bit installer version.It is better for me to install via terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a SourceForge page that offer XAMPP 5.6.20 compiled for Linux 32-bit architecture, in which XAMPP 5.6.20 is compatible for 16.04 Ubuntu version.

To install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type following command one-by-one:

```
wget "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.20/xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run"
sudo su
chmod +x xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run
./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Apache friends does not supports 32 Bit architecture for XAMPP any more [[1]](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=73995).

Instead of using XAMPP I suggest you to use a pure LAMP:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

[More info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

Answer (score 0):

There was a SourceForge page that offer XAMPP 5.6.20 compiled for Linux 32-bit architecture, in which XAMPP 5.6.20 is compatible for 16.04 Ubuntu version.

To install this, press Ctrl+Alt+T to go to a terminal and type following command one-by-one:

wget "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.20/xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run"

su -

chmod +x xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run

./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run